# Django annotate whether field is null

Tags: python, django

I want to annotate a datetime field to know whether it is null. Something like:

```
Table.objects.all().annotate(date_is_null=XXX(YYY)).values(date_is_null, .....)
```

What do I need to replace `XXX(YYY)` to check if the field is null?

(I'm using `.values().annotate()` later for a `Group By`, so it must be in annotate first)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use an `ExpressionWrapper` to convert a `Q` object to an annotated `BooleanField`:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

Table.objects.annotate(
    date_is_null=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(date=None),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

Here `Q(date=None)` is thus the condition. If the `DateTimeField` has a different name, you should alter the condition accordingly.

You can make the condition more verbose with:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

Table.objects.annotate(
    date_is_null=ExpressionWrapper(
        Q(date__isnull=True),
        output_field=BooleanField()
    )
)
```

Comment: I think this is a bit cleaner: `date_is_null=ExpressionWrapper(Q(some_date__isnull=False), output_field=BooleanField()))` it also allows comparing to non-null. If you agree, please update the answer

Comment: @user972014: but now `date_is_null` will be `True` in case the value is *not* `NULL` :). I think you need to replace `False` with `True`. But will add it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been looking for this solution all afternoon.

Comment: Update 2022: You don't need the ExpressionWrapper anymore, you can just write `Table.objects.annotate(date_is_null=Q(date__isnull=True))`